# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Tm_Googlemap_Helper_Data

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, fatal-error, user-roles

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Mage_Tm_Googlemap_Helper_Data::__() in
>   /home/mypetshop/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Roles.php
>   on line 160

I get this error when I try to Add new roles in my Magento Admin panel or edit an existing role.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, you are using a module called "`Tm_Googlemap`" that has an admin configuration area. When a module uses the admin configuration and role system, it must have a Helper-class defined for translations. I guess you can find the module in `app/code/(local|community)/Tm/Googlemap/`, and it will have a `system.xml` and `adminhtml.xml` in its `etc/`-directory.

There you will find a node like:

```
<tm_googlemap_options module="Tm_Googlemap">[...]
```

Then, go into the module's `config.xml` file. Either there is already a node `global/helper`, or you must create a new one:

```
[...]
<helpers>
    <Tm_Googlemap> <!-- make sure you use the string from modules="..." -->
        <class>Tm_Googlemap_Helper</class>
    </Tm_Googlemap>
</helpers>
[...]
```

After this, check the module directory again. If there ist no folder `Helper/` with a file called `Data.php`, create it. Then, insert these contents:

```
<?php

class Tm_Googlemap_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {}
```

Flush cache, logout and login from the admin panel - it should work then! Make sure to uncomment the line you commented, changes in the `/core/`-directory are no-go im Magento.

Comment: Thanks @simonthesorcerer but
all files exist properly the way you showed in your answer!
I am confused what i have to do?

Comment: Does the string in `module=""` and the helper class from the `config.xml` match? You could also check `adminhtml.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Is this Your module or third party extension? Probably the class Mage_Tm_Googlemap_Helper_Data does not exists, have typo in name or is not defined in module config

```
<global>
  <helpers>
    <module>
      <class>Company_Module_Helper</class>
    </module>
  </helpers>
</global>
```

Also check if this module extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract

Comment: I am new in Magento.
I know the class Mage_Tm_Googlemap_Helper_Data does not exist. 
How to check if this module extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract???
Please guide.

Comment: One thing I can say is this error occurs due to some third party extension (plugin) I have installed but which plugin I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

After all my research found a quick fix.
Just comment the line on which you are getting error.
In my case I commented line no. 160 in app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Roles.php